# Make the first column of table clickable and navigate to another page in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Hi I am working on react, and i one problem in which i have one dynamically generated table and i want the first column of my table to be clickable and navigate to another page.
eg: Here in the below array i have 3 fields in which **name** should be clickable and onclick of this field it will navigate to the another page.

```
tableData: [
    {id: "1", name: "name1", value: "1" },
    {id: "2", name: "name2", value: "2"}
]
```

I the below method **getBody()** takes the data as props in which when i return the **row** it will return the above array.
eg:

```
getBody = () => {
        return this.props.body.map((row, index) => {
            return (
                <tr key={index}>
                    {this.renderRowData(row)}
                </tr>
            )
        });
    }
```

```
 renderRowData = (row) => {
        return this.props.header.map(({ key, checked }, index) => {
            return (
                <td key={index}
                    className={(key === 'status' ? this.getStatusColor(row[key]) : '') ||
                        (key === 'rule_type' ? this.getRuleTypeColor(row[key]) : '')}>
                    <div className="item">
                        {
                            (checked)
                                ? <CheckBox
                                    checked={this.props.selectedValue && this.props.selectedValue.indexOf(row[key]) >= 0}
                                    clicked={() => this.props.onChecked(row[key])} />
                                : null
                        }

                        {
                            this.props.noPrecision === 'true' ?
                                <span className="checkbox-design">{roundOff(row[key], 0)}</span> :
                                <span className="checkbox-design">{roundOff(row[key], 2)}</span>

                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
            );
        });
    };
```

```
export const header = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    value: 'Name',
    checked: true,
  },
```

So here i want to return the row in such a way that its first row should be clickable and navigate to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can render the first column of the table as a react-router `Link`

For example

```
    tableData: [
    {id: "1", name: "name1", value: "1" },
    {id: "2", name: "name2", value: "2"}
    ]

function Table() {
   return (
 <table>
        <thead><tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {tableData.map(r => {
            <tr key={r.id} >
              <td>
                <Link to={name}>{name}</Link>
              </td>
              <td>
                {value}
              </td>
            </tr>
          })}
          </tbody>
      </table>
)

}
```

For reference on using `react-router` link you can refer [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) link

You can refer to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-zqleu?file=/components/Home.js) sandbox

```
 renderRowData = (row) => {
        return this.props.header.map(({ key, checked }, index) => {
        const rowEl = (
      <div className="item">
      {
          (checked)
              ? <CheckBox
                  checked={this.props.selectedValue && this.props.selectedValue.indexOf(row[key]) >= 0}
                  clicked={() => this.props.onChecked(row[key])} />
              : null
      }

      {
          this.props.noPrecision === 'true' ?
              <span className="checkbox-design">{roundOff(row[key], 0)}</span> :
              <span className="checkbox-design">{roundOff(row[key], 2)}</span>

      }
    </div>
    )
            return (
                <td key={index}
                    className={(key === 'status' ? this.getStatusColor(row[key]) : '') ||
                        (key === 'rule_type' ? this.getRuleTypeColor(row[key]) : '')}>
                   {key === 'name' ? <Link to={name}>{rowEl}</Link> : rowEl}
                </td>
            );
        });
    };
```

Comment: Hi Sumanth
```
  <tbody>
                            {this.getBody()}
                        </tbody>
```
Actually i called this method like this so how i would i do this operations as <tr> are genrated dynamically.

Comment: can you share the `renderRowData` method

Comment: @Stackuse1994  onClick of  ` <span className="checkbox-design">{roundOff(row[key], 0)}</span>` you want to navigate am i right?

Comment: Yes, on click of fields of first column. These checkbox are for some other use but on the same column if user want to see page after navigation he should be able to do so,

Comment: @Stackuse1994 You can add a check like if you want the `name` row to have the link check if `key` === name ? <Link to="name" ></Link or render what evet is already there

Comment: Thank you so much Sumanth your code in the sandbox works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use history inside the onClick handle:

```
if (props.history) props.history.push('/otherpage');
```